# Would like to copy the row which are highlighted in sheet 2 to Sheet1 based the header -Excel VB | Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro which copy's the entire Sheet 2 to Sheet 1 based on the headers. But, I would like the code to consider the rows which are highlighted in a specific color.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim Rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim rSize As Long
    Dim Dest As Range
    Dim headerRng As Range
    Dim lDestRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Uncomment after testing

    Sheets("Base Sheet").Select
    i = 0
    Set Rng = Range([D1], [D1].End(xlToRight))
    Set headerRng = Range([D1], [D1].End(xlToRight))

    For Each c In Rng


        Set sCell = Sheets("Roster").Range("1:1").Find(What:=c.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        rSize = Sheets("Roster").Range(sCell.Offset(1, 0), sCell.End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count

        If c.Offset(1, 0).Value <> "" Then
            'c.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Resize(rSize, 1) = Sheets("Roster").Range(sCell.Offset(1, 0), sCell.End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value
            Set Dest = c.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
            If i = 0 Then
            lDestRow = Dest.row
            End If
            If AmIYellow(Cell) And Cell.Value <> "" Then '<~ blank check too
                Set Dest = Output.Cells(DestCounter, 1)
            If Dest.row < lDestRow Then
            Set Dest = Cells(lDestRow, Dest.Column)
            End If

            Sheets("Roster").Range(sCell.Offset(1, 0), sCell.End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            Dest.Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste


        Else
            'c.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rSize, 1).Value = Range(sCell.Offset(1, 0), sCell.End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value

            Range(sCell.Offset(1, 0), sCell.End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            Set Dest = c.Offset(1, 0)

            If Dest.row < lDestRow Then
            Set Dest = Cells(lDestRow, Dest.Column)
            End If

            Dest.Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If

        i = i + 1
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: So what is the 'super-secret' specific color. and is it applied to the entire row?

Comment: It will be Red and Yes, it's applied to the entire row.

Comment: What's the difference between rng and headerRng ? If none then why both?

Comment: headerRng can be deleted. It is a duplicate
Set headerRng = Range([D1], [D1].End(xlToRight))

Comment: ... and Set Rng = Range([D1], [D1].End(xlToRight)). I don't see a difference.

Comment: Is `If AmIYellow(Cell) ...` supposed to look for cell with a red 'fill'?

Comment: My Bad. I was trying to achieve this in multiple ways which did not work. Please delete

                If AmIYellow(Cell) And Cell.Value <> "" Then '<~ blank check too
                    Set Dest = Output.Cells(DestCounter, 1)

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier if you just stated what headers identify the columns of values (only the red ones) are to be copied somewhere else.

Comment: That's right. Sheet 2 has multiple columns and Sheet 1 will have only 5 or 6 column with headers of Sheet2.

With above script, Sheet 1 will pull the complete row; based on the headers from Sheet 2 (Ex: 10). Now, I need to modify the script a bit where it will pull only highlighted(in Red) Rows from Sheet 2 based on the headers(Ex: 2 rows).

Comment: @Jeeped Any help?